# Sql- how to use relational field in condition

Tags: mysql, yii2

I have three tables which is mapped like this:  *paymentDetails <-employee<-designation.*

Now I have to get datas from paymentDetails table by particular designation of employee..

```
select * 
from paymentDetails
where payment_date=date and employee.designation.desig_id=2;
```

And I am using Yii2 framework How can I achieve this in Yii2.

I get *unknown column error*. How to resolve this ?

Comment: Put the tables you want to use in the `from` clause.

Comment: the column *employee.designation.desig_id* does not exist in table *paymentDetails*

Comment: paymentDetails table has one to one relationship with employee and employee has relationship with designation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  hi, do you mean to use like    select * from pamentDetails,employee where payment_date=date and employee.designation.desig_id=2;

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi, As your input i got it working. but my problem is yet be solved in yii2. I rewritten the query like this. select * from paymentDetails pd,employee e where pd.payment_date=date and e.desig_id=2; but i am not able to use in yii2 framework. Thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select(*)
    ->from('paymentDetails')
    ->where('payment_date=date')    
    ->andWhere('employee.designation.desig_id=2')
```

Comment: I have tried like this... Getting same error. I thing the issue is with sql or reltionship.. query can not access the designation details by employee.designation.deisg_id...

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from paymentDetails
where payment_date=date and employee.designation.desig_id=2;
```

this will not work in SQL either, it is beacause you are using the tables employee and designation and you do not actually join them in any way.

Now you have not given us any details regarding the name of the models, but it should be something like

```
$paymentDetails = PaymentDetails::find()->joinWith('employee.designation')-where(['employee.designation.desig_id' => 2, 'payment_date' => 'date'])->all();
```

This will execute 
select * 
from paymentDetails JOIN employee ON 'theDefinedRelation' JOIN designation ON 'theSecondDefinedRelation' where payment_date=date and employee.designation.desig_id=2;

Anyway, it will be a long day, if you do not know why the SQL fails you have to learn SQL first.

Comment: Hi, I dont think that I require this kind of complex query. This is just to display a payment detail list by the designation of the employee and the particular date of the payment. I found the query which was executed in phpmyadmin . I used the same in sqlDataProvider which throws a database exception while adding parameters. Thanks to the comment made by @Gordon Linoff.. But now i stuck with yii2 framework.